# Why is the 'Move' box always disabled on our SRX 500 running JunOS 12?

Tags: juniper, junos

I've been trying to determine what has happened with the SRX500's we have at work. They are running JunOS 12 [12.1X46-D40.2].

For some reason the 'Move' box in the upper right of the Security > Policy > Apply Policy page is always greyed out, so we are unable to visually re-arrange rules from the UI and resort to the CLI each time.

While this isn't a serious problem, it is an inconvenience, particularly when dealing with large rulesets.

Unfortunately I do not know the history behind this, as it was like this when I started with the company.

Is anyone familiar with this problem? My Google-fu is not revealing any helpful questions or forum posts.

Comment: I despise the GUIs but this is definitely one of those things that is WAY easier through a GUI. It could be that rules not created thru the GUI are not command-able by it. Start looking through JunOS release notes I bet you find a "fixed" for this somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out how to resolve this. The problem is the interface remembers if you've ever clicked a column to sort the list. Once you have, the sort will be remembered until your cache is cleared or you use the `Clean Sort` option from the dropdown that appears on any column when hovering it. This will re-enable the ability to sort and move your rule order from the GUI.

[image]